# Change vertical space before and after list of tables and list of figures in Koma script

Tags: spacing, koma-script

I am trying to make a short list of tables and list of figures in the appendix of a document, using the general commands `\listoffigures` and `listoftables`. That works, but there is a lot of abundant vertical space added. I want the appendix to be very concise.

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}% scrreprt
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Exemplary figure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Exemplary table}
    \end{table}
    \section{Appendix}
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

If you run the above code, the list of tables and the list of figures are both on a new page. I would like them to have on the same page as the section "Appendix". How can this be done in Koma script?

More generally, I was looking for a way to have a new list of tables and list of figures, separately for the appendix. But that seems to be even more complicated than achieving what I want to do, as in my case, I am not using the commands for list of tables and list of figures in the main document. So I think it is easier to just use them in the Appendix.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Why do you use `\section` for the appendix instead of `\chapter` with `scrreprt`? Maybe you are searching for option `listof=leveldown` (see the manual for more information).

Comment: Because without this option the lists are just chapters (and with the option sections), you can alternatively or additionally configure them using `\RedeclareSectionCommand` before them. You could also do this change using `\BeforeTOCHead` to make it local to one of the lists.

Comment: @cabohah thanks for the hint. I added `listof=leveldown`, but that does only resolve half of the issue. the second list is still put on a new page.

Comment: @ghx12 No, with the change in your example the second list is not put on a new page. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the lists of something are chapters in `scrreprt`. And so the titles are formatted as chapter headings. By default chapters start a new page and add some vertical space above.

But the classes provide several configuration features for the lists of something. For example, there is option `listof=leveldown` to change the headings level. With `scrreprt` or `scrbook` the options make them to be sections instead of chapters. (With `scrartcl` they would be subsections instead of section.) Sections do not force a new page and insert less vertical space above:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,listof=leveldown]{scrreprt}% scrreprt
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Exemplary figure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Exemplary table}
    \end{table}
    \section{Appendix}
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several more features. For example, you can explicitly define a new command for the heading. Or you can change the style of sections, e.g.:

```latex
% This example should not be used as it is.
% It is just to illustrate some of the available features.
\documentclass[12pt,listof=leveldown]{scrreprt}% scrreprt
\usepackage{xcolor}
\BeforeTOCHead[lof]{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\color{green}]{section}%
}
\BeforeTOCHead[lot]{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\color{blue},beforeskip=0pt,runin=false,afterskip=0pt]{section}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Exemplary figure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Exemplary table}
    \end{table}
    \section{Appendix}
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

BTW: IMHO it would make more sense, to use `\addchap{Appendix}` instead of `\section{Appendix}`.

Separated lists for the main part and the appendix are also possible. But because you've explicitly told, that you don't need this, I'll not show it.

Comment: thanks very helpful. Just one question: how can I change the vertical space after the last entry of list of tables and the header "list of figures"? I tried to change the inputs of `\BeforeTOCHead[lot]`, but that didnt change anything in my document

Comment: You can change the space before or after *the heading*. So in the example to change the space after the `\listoftables` you can change the space before the heading of the `\listoffigures`. To really change the space after one of the lists, just use `\vspace` after the list (can also be done from within the document preamble, using `\AfterStartingTOC`). If you have problems in doing it, please ask a new *detailed* question. General questions mostly can be answered generally. Detailed answers for general questions are more complicated and often harder to understand.